# Usage of "infinities"

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

What is the usage of the word *infinities*? Is the term *infinite infinities* correct, and how is it used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from use in mathematics, it may also appear in poetry.  Some examples found using Google...

[But, my love for you is infinite infinities!](http://allpoetry.com/poem/8892843-Infinite-by-X415)

[To infinite infinities,/as the spirits He set free.](http://www.poems-and-quotes.com/life/poems.php?id=1168085)

Comment: Even I find those poems cutesy beyond the point of nausea and look, I have a unicorn avatar plus I quite like rainbows and glitter.

Comment: @z7sg Ѫ - Yeah. I'm not sure it sees much use, outside of Vogon poetry.